# Sending asynchronous requests without a pre-defined task list

Tags: python, asynchronous, optimization

I need to send requests continuously, at specific intervals. I have a script that uses threads, but it heavily loads the server. Additionally, I prefer to have this not in a single session and would like to avoid cached responses

I wanted to rewrite everything using asyncio, but I encountered an issue where I need to predefine a task list, and there's a significant delay between 'gather' calls.

Comment: do you want to send the request to only one URL or different URLs? give more detail pls.

Comment: to the same url, only different cookies and proxies are used

Comment: can you provide the script you wrote pls? we can improve it or write a better version of it

Comment: I added pseudocode to the answer

Comment: And ideally, there should be as little variation as possible between the intervals of responses, meaning that this number should be as close as possible to the interval between requests.

Comment: I tested, most of the load is created by requests, load cpu, ram normal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../")

import time
from loguru import logger
from auth import Auth
import requests
import threading
import orjson
from utils import retry_on_exception


logger.add("logs.log", filter=lambda record: record["extra"].get("logs") == True)


# URLS constants
URL = "https:....."
# .....


CONST1 = "..."

CONST2 = "..."

data_list = []
locker = threading.Lock()


@retry_on_exception
def func1(acc, info):
    data = {
        # data CONST1
    }

    resp = requests.post(url=URL,
                         headers=acc.get_headers(),
                         cookies=acc.get_cookies(),
                         json=data)


@retry_on_exception
def func2(acc, info1, info2):
    data = {
        # info1 info2 CONST2
    }
    resp = requests.post(URL,
                         headers=acc.get_headers(),
                         cookies=acc.get_cookies(),
                         json=data)
    if resp.json()["code"] == "..." and resp.json().get("error"):
        logger.info("...", logs=True)
        return

    logger.debug("{resp}", resp=resp, resp_text=resp.text)
    info = resp.json()["..."]
    func1(info=info, acc=acc)


def exception_execute(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.exception("{ex}", ex=ex, console=True)

    return wrapper


@exception_execute
def func3(acc, cookies, proxy):
    resp = requests.get(URL, cookies=cookies, proxies=proxy)
    print(resp, time.time()) # use print because logs loads more cpu

    resp_json = orjson.loads(resp.text)
    infos = resp_json["..."]
    goods_infos = resp_json["..."]

    for i in infos:
        info1 = i["..."]
        info2 = i["..."]
        info3 = i["..."]

        if True or False: # if with received information
            with locker:
                if info1 not in data_list:
                    data_list.append(info1)
                else:
                    continue

            func2(info1=info1,
                  info2=info2,
                  acc=acc)

            logger.info("...", console=True, logs=True)
            logger.info("{info1}", info1=info1, console=True, logs=True)
            logger.info("{info2}", info2=info2, console=True, logs=True)



def get_acc():
    acc_paths = [
        # acc path list
    ]

    acc_list = [Auth(path).get_cookies() for path in acc_paths]

    while True:
        for acc in acc_list:
            yield acc


def main():
    proxy_list = [
        {}
    ]

    main_acc = Auth(r"accounts/..")
    main_acc.ensure_auth()

    acc_gen = get_acc()

    while True:
        for proxy in proxy_list:
            time.sleep(0.04)
            t = threading.Thread(target=func3, args=(acc, next(acc_gen), proxy))
            t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The extent of your code answer is appreciated! One thing that would help both the person asking the question, and any future readers, would be some details on the choices you make for the code. This could be either comments in the code, or perhaps breaking up the code with text discussions of the steps you take and the code that implements those steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).